# iRedMail made mail page default

Tags: server, email, nginx

I have installed iRedMail on my machine that is running Ubuntu server. I also have a website running on nginx. But for some reason after installation of iRedMail the mail control panel (SOGo to be more precise) become the main page of my website. It's even impossible to go to the main page of the website or any other page by manually entering the file name after the domain name (if I do so, it just downloads the index file to my computer) and I'm constantly appear to be on the mydomain.lts/SOGo page. I want to make my website appear as a main page as it should be and SOGo page only when I manually entering /SOGo after the domain name or getting redirected to it from my website. Here is my nginx configuration:

````
#
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/site;
        server_name _;

        location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
}```
(Default config of nginx, except /var/www/html folder is replaced with /var/www/site)
````